# prebid server amp config hosted by appnexus

Tags: prebid.js, header-bidding, prebid

I am trying to create a config to use on the appnexus Prebid Server. It is not working.

Where do i get the value for "id"? The example value is "some-request-id". What does that mean?
Where do I get the value for imp > id? The example value is "some-impression-id". What does that mean?

I have tried to find examples, but cannot find documentation on where to get the values to fill in those variables.

Below is the default example.

```
{
"id": "some-request-id",
"site": {
    "page": "prebid.org"
},
"ext": {
    "prebid": {
        "targeting": {
            "pricegranularity": {  // This is equivalent to the deprecated "pricegranularity": "medium"
                "precision": 2,
                "ranges": [{
                    "max": 20.00,
                    "increment": 0.10
                }]
            }
        }
    }
},
"imp": [
    {
        "id": "some-impression-id",
        "banner": {
            "format": [
                {
                    "w": 300,
                    "h": 250
                }
            ]
        },
        "ext": {
            "appnexus": {
                // Insert parameters here
            },
            "rubicon": {
                // Insert parameters here
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request ID is an openrtb field to assign an ID for this auction. Since there exists no analytics in AMP we can use to keep track of auctions this can be any arbitrary string.

Likewise the imp.id is an identifier to keep track of which bids belong to which imps (notice that "imp" is an array). Since there can only be one imp in an AMP request, again it does not matter and you can assign any arbitrary string to this.